# Updating a column of the db after inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `lotto_epins` with the following columns

`lpin_id, lpin_serial, lpin_ec_id, lpin_epin, lpin_status`

After inserting using PHP, I wish to update the column `lpin_serial` by adding 0 in front of the `lpin_id` for a serial no.

I tried the following mysql trigger but it does not work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `capital` BEFORE INSERT ON `lotto_epins`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
SET lpin_serial = LPAD(lpin_id,15,0) 
END;
```

How can I correctly update the column after inserting?

Comment: Note: using triggers to implement business logic is considered a bad practice, try to keep the BL in the BL layer on your application. Triggers can turn the problems hard to find and increase maintenance (general speaking)

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER capital BEFORE INSERT ON lotto_epins 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   SET NEW.lpin_serial = LPAD(NEW.lpin_id,15,0);
END //
delimiter ;
```